# Self hosted gitlab is slow, how to make it faster?

Tags: gitlab, self-hosting, gitlab-omnibus

We've been running self hosted gitlab on AWS for a couple of years now, and with everything growing (repo size, board size, pipeline size, team size), things have slowed down considerably, to point where I'm losing my mind.

Just as a reference, here are some loading times. I've checked both, performance with the performance bar (entering `p+b` in gitlab) and also checking out the networking tab in the browser and how long it takes to finish.

- Loading the board, perf checked with `p+b`, longest request (/api/graphql): ~5s
- Loading merge requests page, networking finished: ~2s
- Loading pipelines, networking finished: ~8s

What options do we have to make gitlab faster again?

Answer (score 3):

I've done research and surprisingly not that much comes up (don't you people have the same problem?!). The only remedy I've found was changing the instance types, and those **do** make a difference. So an option, if you have the money to spare, is to get better machines.

## Setup for Performance Tests

The slowest to load was the pipelines page and the board, so there I've conducted the speed tests. I took several measurements and averaged the results. On the board I checked the performance bar `p+b` longest request (`/api/graphql`) and on the pipelines page I checked the networking tab with caching disabled, until all requests were finished.

I conducted the tests on a gitlab instance where it was only me playing around and no other team members, so I cannot tell how much the results degrade when more people are working.

## Machine comparison

| Machine Type | Price | vcpu | RAM | clock speed | Loading Board | Loading Pipelines |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t2.large | $70 / month | 2 | 8 | 3.3 | 5s | 5s |
| t3.large | $60 / month | 2 | 8 | 3.1 | 5s | 6s |
| t2.2xlarge | $270 / month | 8 | 32 | 3.3 | 2s | 5.5s |
| z1d.large | $135 / month | 2 | 8 | 4 | 5s | 3.5s |
| m5zn.xlarge | $240 / month | 4 | 16 | 4.5 | 2s | 3.3s |

It seems that loading the board is rather sensitive to number of cores or memory while loading the pipelines is sensitive to clock speed. I'm not a pro with the different instance types on AWS, maybe there's some other magic ingredient (low latency networking?) in m5zn that makes it the fastest, those are just the factors that came to my mind.

I also tested changing the disk from `gp2` to `gp3` with maximum IOPS and throughput, but that didn't change the performance.

## Conclusion

For an all-round ok-ish performance, choose the `m5zn.xlarge` instance. It is way above the requirements that gitlab claims are necessary, but it speeds up things significantly.